# change background color surface light/dark jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to start with jetpack compose and it's getting complicated to be able to change the background automatically according to the theme chosen by the user (light dark).

I am editing the colors from theme.kt

```
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
primary = Purple80,
secondary = PurpleGrey80,
tertiary = Pink80,
surface = Color(0xFF0BB000),
background = Color(0xFF0BB000),
onBackground = Color(0xFF0BB000))
```

The problem is that when I run the app, the background color is still grey.

I think the problem is that my app doesn't take the colors from the theme, since I tried to set it directly, but it doesn't change the background color either.

```
Surface ( color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
```

If anyone has any ideas why it doesn't change color automatically and point me to it, I'd appreciate it.

I can set the palette again from my activity and change it, it depends on the mode chosen by the user, but it is not an optimal solution and it looks ugly.

I leave my activity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        TruequeGualeguaychuTheme {
            Surface ( color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background){
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .wrapContentHeight(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    text = "Hello Android!",
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

It should have a green background but it does not take the color declared in ( background = Color(0xFF0BB000) )

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that newer versions of android have dynamic colors that use a color palette based on the system.
By default the theme has this option activated which limits the setting that one can make of the color palette.

```
 dynamicColor: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is change `dynamicColor` to `false`,
For example:

```
setContent {
    TestTheme(dynamicColor = false) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        )
    }
}
```

then you need to add `background` property with the desired color to `Theme.kt`

in my case I added `BackgroundWhite` to `Color.kt`

```
    private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
        primary = Purple80,
        secondary = PurpleGrey80,
        tertiary = Pink80,
        background = BackgroundWhite,
    )
    
    private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
        primary = Purple40,
        secondary = PurpleGrey40,
        tertiary = Pink40,
        background = BackgroundWhite
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented similar functions before,but it's at Jb-compose desktop.Provide a reference:

MainApp.kt:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
@Preview
fun launchApp() {
  MaterialTheme(
    colors = darkColors(
                primary = MyColor.primaryColor,
                primaryVariant = MyColor.primaryColor,
                secondary = MyColor.primaryColor,
                secondaryVariant = MyColor.primaryColor,
                background = MyColor.darkBackgroundColor,
                surface = MyColor.darkBackgroundColor,
                onPrimary = Color.White,
                onSecondary = Color.White,
                onBackground = Color.White,
                onSurface = Color.White,
                error = Color.Red,
                onError = Color.White
            ),
        ){
           //...
                 }
}
```

Main.kt:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) = application {
    Window(
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
        icon = painterResource("icon/xx.ico"),
        title = "xx ${RuntimeContext.APP_VERSION}",
    ) {
        MainApp.launchApp()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The part it looks like you're missing is the hinted at in @vaspike's answer.  All views that should utilize your custom theme should derive from an instance of the theme.  For example:

```
@Composable
fun MyTheme(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = LightColors, // A list of key/values I define.
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
fun HomePage(){
    MyTheme(){
        // composables that use the theme.
    }
}
```

This comes from the example found here, https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-theming#3

Answer (score 0):

`val Colors.myBackgroundColor get() = if (isLight) Color.White else Color.Black`

you can create color like this and use this color in Surface background color.

```
    Surface(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.myBackgroundColor)) {
// your code 
}
```